# Why can't PowerShell connect to one of my remote hosts in my domain using WinRM?

Tags: windows, powershell-remoting, winrm

I have a problem on one of my machine when I try to use it as WinRM client to connect into another machine. The scenario is:

- The problem machine (VM A) on Window 7, has WinRM enable already (already ran winrm quickconfig, Enable-PSRemoting), then I add IP of the remote machine (VM C) into Trusted host of VM A, then run `Test-WSMan` and I get this error:

> <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault"
> Code="2150858770" Machine="VM A Name"><f:Message>The client cannot connect to the
> destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is
> running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the
> WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the
> destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze
> and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". </f:Message></f:WSManFault>

The error in Windows Event Log:

```xml
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WinRM" Guid="{A7975C8F-AC13-49F1-87DA-5A984A4AB417}" /> 
      <EventID>142</EventID> 
      <Version>0</Version> 
      <Level>2</Level> 
      <Task>10</Task> 
      <Opcode>2</Opcode> 
      <Keywords>0x4000000000000002</Keywords> 
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-11-10T19:33:07.625538700Z" /> 
      <EventRecordID>29783</EventRecordID> 
      <Correlation ActivityID="{0350CC40-F800-0000-FB6D-459B2E3BD201}" /> 
      <Execution ProcessID="6284" ThreadID="7548" /> 
      <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-WinRM/Operational</Channel> 
      <Computer>[VM A Name]</Computer> 
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1317227024-500078832-2798313031-10175" /> 
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="operationName">Identify</Data> 
      <Data Name="errorCode">2150858770</Data> 
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

- Tested the winrm config and Enable-PSRemoting on VM C (VM C is Windows 2012R2)
- I tried these steps with other machine (VM B) to connect to VM C, enable WinRM by winrm quickconfig then run Test-WSMan, then it passes. So the problem is not on VM C.
- I tried to run Test-WSMan localhost on VM A, WinRM is working on this machine. Tried to open port 5985 and 5986 for WinRM HTTP and HTTPS (netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM-HTTP" dir=in localport=5985 protocol=TCP action=allow). I also tried to Test-NetConnection on port 5985 from a Windows 2012 to VM A. Disabled all Firewall rules on VM A.

I have no idea what is the problem on VM A.

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue any more since Windows 2012R2 in EoL and later versions of Windows has remoting enabled on servers by default.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the machines in the same domain?

Make sure Both machines have each other as trusted hosts.

For example, i had to set TrustedHosts = "*" on my server to be able to send scripts to all my clients from that server.

My clients had to have my server as trusted host as well of course.

I was a bit confused over the fact that the sender/server had to trust the reciever/client.

Comment: They are in WORKGROUP but I will try your suggestion

Comment: Did i work? and did you make sure to add each server to the other as trusted? And if so, did you add them by IP or by machine name ?

Comment: unfortunately, those machines were cleaned up as this issue was there a year ago, I couldn't reproduce it now. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.
FYI, I used remote access based on IP only